# Storing ArrayList of Points to a file in Java for Android

Tags: java, android

I am unable to write the ArrayList to a file. I am doing as following, what is the correct way? 
 If I don't add 'pt' into arraylist, process goes fine and it gets saved. 
os.writeObject(arr);  - after this line debugger goes to IOException. Code:

```
//holder class implements Serializable
transient ArrayList<Point> arr;
transient Point pt;
//I've tried without transient, same result 
//
arr = new ArrayList<Point>();
pt = new Point();
p.x = 10;
p.y = 20;
arr.add(pt);
//If I don't add 'pt' into arraylist, process goes fine and it gets saved.
//
String strStorageDirectory = this.getFilesDir() + "/DataFiles";
final File DataStorageDirectory = new File(strStorageDirectory);
File lfile = new File(DataStorageDirectory, "samplefile.bin");
FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(lfile);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(arr);//after this line debugger goes to IOException
        //I've tried with os.writeObject((Serializable)arr), same result;
        os.flush();//I've tried removing it, same result
        os.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the `stacktrace` of your exception?

Comment: did you define your own Point class? or you use the built in java Point class?

Comment: @Remdroid - I am using built-in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping [Point](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html)s in ArrayList, you can add two [Integer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html)s per point. Integer supports [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html), `Point` does not.

Answer (score 3):

To seralize the `List<Point>`, your `Point` class must be [serializable](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

```
public class Point implements Serializable {...}
```

I'd suggest to use JSON ([gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) API to read and write objects directly.

Comment: android.graphics.Point is not Serializable.

Comment: I am using built-in Point class.

Comment: That's why I've suggested gson (JSON) API.

Comment: @AmitD - yes, that is exception as well - 'java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Point'. So there is no way to make it Serializable, right?

Comment: For more information read - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: @Prasoon Create wrapper like I have suggested, or use JSON API as suggested by AVD. By using List of Integers you will land in problems in which if the sequence goes wrong whole data will be no more of use.

Answer (score 1):

`android.graphics.Point` is not `Serializable`.

Make a new class `Point` `Serializable` which will copy `android.graphics.Point` in to custom `Point` class

```
class Point implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    Point(android.graphics.Point point)
    {
        this.x  = point.x;
        this.y= point.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, but last time I tried there was a huge hit to performance. If performance is not important than no problem.