# Write and read custom object to file android

Tags: android, file, object

I have the following problem. I am designing application for handwriting. 
I don't know how to write and read my Object (LogInfo) into a file. I know that I should override write and read methods, but I am still not sure how to do it. Could anyone give me clear answer to my question?

My class is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Point;

public class LogInfo implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5777674941129067422L;
    transient public static List<Point[][]> strokes;
    transient public static List<byte[]> codes;

    public LogInfo()
    {
        strokes = new ArrayList<Point[][]>();
        codes = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
    }

    private synchronized void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        stream.defaultWriteObject();
        //stream.writeInt(strokes.size());
        //Point[][] pointsArray;
        //for (int i=0; i<strokes.size(); i++)
        //{
        //  pointsArray = ((Point[][])strokes.get(i));
        //  for (int j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++)
        //      for (int k = 0; k < pointsArray[j].length; k++)
        //      {
        //          stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].x);
        //          stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].y);
        //          //stream.writeObject(elementData[i]);
        //      }
        //}
        stream.writeInt(codes.size());
        for (int i=0; i<codes.size(); i++)
        {
            stream.write(codes.get(i));
        }
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        int codesSize = stream.readInt();
        for (int i=0; i<codesSize; i++)
        {
            byte[] buffer = null;
            stream.read(buffer, 0, 3);
            codes.add(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Strokes is an ArrayList containing 2-dimensional arrays of Point type (corresponding to stroke number and points related with it)

Codes is an array in which I store characters (3 bytes = 1 character)

So if I write "A" using 2 strokes,strokes and codes size is 2, and codes contains character A written on 3 bytes.

Could someone tell me how can I write and read this objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution.

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    stream.defaultWriteObject();
    stream.writeInt(strokes.size());
    Point[][] pointsArray = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < strokes.size(); i++)
    {
        pointsArray = ((Point[][])strokes.get(i));
        stream.writeInt(pointsArray.length);
        for (int j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++)
        {
            stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j].length);
            for (int k = 0; k < pointsArray[j].length; k++)
            {
                stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].x);
                stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].y);
                //stream.writeObject(elementData[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    int size = codes.size();
    stream.writeInt(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        stream.write(codes.get(i));
    }
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    stream.defaultReadObject();
    int strokesSize = stream.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < strokesSize; i++)
    {
        int arrayXSize = stream.readInt();
        Point[][] points = new Point[arrayXSize][];
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayXSize; j++)
        {
            int arrayYSize = stream.readInt();
            points[j] = new Point[arrayYSize];
            for (int k = 0; k < arrayYSize; k++)
                points[j][k] = new Point(stream.readInt(), stream.readInt());
        }
        strokes.add(points);
    }

    int codesSize = stream.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < codesSize; i++)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
        stream.read(buffer, 0, 3);
        codes.add(buffer);
    }
}
```

It is working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since Point is not serializable.  You can have a custom "point" class with x & y and a transient Point that is derived from it.  That way, you can use the default readObject and writeObject.

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172650/storing-arraylist-of-points-to-a-file-in-java-for-android)

Comment: I think that Point class is not Serializable.

Comment: Also when I use default implementation the only information that is written to file is Class path and some random chars (????com.myapp.LogInfo??f@Stb xp) which for sure is not the information that it should be. Why there is a class name written to a file?

Comment: No one knows the answer? :(

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the Point, yes it is not serializable, updated my answer